# Generate XML from xsd-files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, validation, xsd

I have a xmlshema with complex types, these types are defined in other xml-schemas (other xsd files). The problem is: I don't have the attribute schemalocation in my xml-schemas. it looks like this:

see the screenshot:

[image: xsd with embeded xsd-files]

the xml-schemas where the complex types are defined, are not online under this address :http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/...
there are local in folders eCH-0007, eCH-0010 .....

I want to generate an xml from these xml-schemas using C#.

Comment: Side note: please avoid "searched alot", thank you notes and general whining in the post. Instead show code you've tried as result of spending "days" on research of the problem. Also try to post text (sources, errors, XML/HTML/XSD...) as text, not images.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not very detailed. But you can try this as a general aproach when working with XSD Files.

1. Download and isntall [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/).
2. Add the XSD to your project
3. Generate the DataContract Classes via WSCF.blue
4. Serialize them if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate it by Microsoft tool [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)

1 Generate class. For example `xsd /c /language:CS XSDSchemaFile.xsd`

2 Serialize this class to xml

Comment: i dont want to generate classes. i only want to generate xml-document. my question is: how to load complex  types from other xsd-files to a main xmlschema?